# Brouwer degree is independent choice of regular value

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was reading Milnor's differential topology book in page 27,there is a statement :

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be smooth map with $X$ and $Y$ be same dimension,such
> that both of them are oriented , we further assume $X$ is compact and
> $Y$ is connected.
>
> denote the Brouwe degree by $$\text{deg}(f)_y = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}
>  \text{sgn}(\det(df_x))$$ prove it does not depend on the regular value
> $y$ we choose.in other words deg as function of y is constant.

The idea is :to prove that deg is locally constant,then by connectess
it's contant everywhere

since we know for the setting above,any regular value $y$.in fact exist a pile of neiborhood $V_1,V_2,...V_n \subset M$ such that diffeomorphic to neiborhood of $y$， that is exist local diffeomorphism $V_i\to U_y$,as y varies in $U_y$ will not change the number of term in the sum

**the question is why $ \text{sgn}(\det(df_x))$ will also not change as y varies in $U_y$**,the intuition is easy that is as $y$ change a little bit,$x$ will change a liile bit,hence det will not change too much to filp the sign How to prove it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's far simpler. If $f$ maps each $V_i$ diffeomorphically to $U$, then $df_x$ is an isomorphism from $T_xV_i$ to $T_{f(x)}U$ for every $x\in V_i$. In particular, $df_x$ is either orientation-preserving for all $x\in V_i$ or orientation-reversing for all $x\in V_i$. (If you choose a parametrizations/charts, then you can look at the square matrices, and their determinants vary continuously; one cannot change from positive determinant to negative determinant without passing through $0$, but this would violate the fact that the matrices are all non-singular.)

Comment: thanks, It seems in the proof of  "orientation-reversing/preserving for all point in the small neiborhood" using the fact that $x$ varies in a connected domain,then  due to conitnuity maps connected set to connected set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Does this result depend on the oriented of manifold?If the manifold is non oriented does this result still holds?

Comment: Yes, I’m using smoothness to infer that the determinant is continuous. Milnor’s result is for oriented manifolds only; otherwise, you can define only mod 2 degree.

Comment: does this proof need $V_i$ to be connected?

Comment: We started with $U$ connected, of course, so each $V_i$ is necessarily connected, yes.

Comment: I can't figure out why $U$ is connected? can you provide a bit hint?

Comment: Hi can we do as follows: since topological manifold has basis of coordinate ball,hence we can select  one coordinate ball inside it,which is automatically connected?